# How to configure a non dockerized nginx to serve static files from a docker container?

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy

#### Description

I have installed NGINX on a ubuntu server. It works and i can run different websites with static files from the same server.
Installed docker now and build an image, pushed it to this ubuntu server and run it with docker. I can reach the site with static files when i call it `server-ip:port`.

#### Problem

I don't know, how to say nginx where the static files are. Because they are inside the docker container.

#### Nginx conf

```
server {
        
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name sub.domain.com www.sub.domain.com;
        
        root <------ what here?
        
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:7000;
        }

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        charset utf-8;

         # php fpm
         location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
          allow all;
          log_not_found off;
          access_log off;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
          allow all;
          log_not_found off;
          access_log off;
        } 

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

        # basic cache control
        location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv)$ {
            expires 30d;
            add_header Cache-Control "public,max-age=31536000";
            access_log off;
        }

        # svg, fonts
        location ~* \.(?:svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
            expires 30d;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            add_header Cache-Control "public,max-age=31536000";
            access_log off;
        }

        # gzip
        gzip on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_proxied any;
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

}
```

#### Question

Can Nginx, which is installed on the server, **not inside a docker container**, serve the static files from the public folder inside Docker container?

Answer (score 0):

File inside a container are of course simply stored on the host filesystem, so you *can* make it work. Assuming that Docker is using the `overlay2` storage driver (which is generally the case these days), you can get the path to the container root filesystem like this:

```
$ docker inspect mycontainer -f '{{ .GraphDriver.Data.MergedDir }}'
```

Which will output something like:

```
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ec046389c3a9e0cfb2a0ab2875ad8f660556fa086de9062f3231a0c6ea0a4e93/merged
```

Just append the path inside the container to that path. For example, if you know the files in your container are at `/var/www/htdocs`, then you would need:

```
root /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ec046389c3a9e0cfb2a0ab2875ad8f660556fa086de9062f3231a0c6ea0a4e93/merged/var/www/htdocs
```

But there are a *lot* of reasons why this is a bad idea, among them:

- This is fragile, because it depends on the storage driver your Docker daemon is using
- The path is going to be different every time you start a new container
- This won't work if the files in which you are interested are stored on a Docker volume

You are generally much better off if you treat your containers like a black box from the perspective of the host.

Comment: thanks for your answer :)
So the better solution would be to create a second container and make it a NGINX container and put it in the same network as my application container. Then the NGINX on the server simply forward to the NGINX container which can serve the static files.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution, i was looking for, is a mount.

On the host i create a directory:

`path/to/hostdirectory`

Then i create a storage with docker

```
docker volume create --driver local \
    --opt type=none \
    --opt device=path/to/hostdirectory \
    --opt o=bind \
    <volume-name>
```

Then i run the image with this command:

`docker run -it -d -p 127.0.0.1:7000:7000 --name <containr-name> -v <volume-name>:path/inside/container <image-name>`

For a description of `-it`, `-d` and `-p` you can run `docker run --help`.
I prefer to make the port of the image only locally available. Therefore i put the 127.0.0.1 in front of `7000:7000`.

Inside the nginx conf file it looks like this:
`root path/to/hostdirectory`
This way NGINX can serve static files from this folder for example.